# VMware vs virtualbox for mac osx guest, does vmware support guest additions?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware

I spent hours downloading and setting up an image for mac os sierra for virtualbox

then I find out there is no guest additions for mac osx from virtualbox. So graphics slow and laggy. Resolutions not supported. Copy paste between host and guest? nope. Share folder host and guest? nope.

Would have been good knowing that before going all down the road.

can vmware provide that?

Comment: OS X isn't licensed to run on anything other than Apple hardware, so there are no guest additions available [policy decision by Oracle to conform with Apple's licensing.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMware of course won't support "guest additions" since those are VirtualBox drivers.

VMware Fusion does support running macOS as a guest and therefore should include VMware Tools (VMware's equivalent of VirtualBox's guest additions) for macOS.

Note that VMware Fusion is a Mac-only product: you are still expected to run macOS on Apple hardware to comply with the macOS EULA.